# Create Event or Event-based Goal from Acquisition -> Social -> Network Referrals

Tags: google-analytics, goals, analytics-events

My objective is to setup a Goal for Social Network Referrals (no need to track specific networks). From the Goal creation options it appears the only way this is possible is by creating an Event-based Goal. It seems, then, that I need to modify my tracking code to properly trigger Social Network Referral events when a page is loaded.

**Q: How can I modify my tracking code to register a Social Network Referral Event with the ultimate purpose of goal tracking?**

**EDIT:** If there's a way to setup goal tracking based on Social Network Referrals without editing my tracking code then that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

After you set an [event-based goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415) (smart goal), setup your [social interactions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions). [This tutorial](https://blog.hootsuite.com/tracking-social-media-in-google-analytics/) is helpful too.

Comment: As I said, there currently is no way I can see to set an event-based goal using Social Network Referrals which is what I need. Social Interactions are not what I'm talking about, but thank you for the info.

Comment: as i understand you are looking for the ways to add to third part sites your own event tracking code? this will be hardly possible, only if these sites provide any way to do so. Other way is to track them with their referrers, but i doubt it would be possible on the event level, only on visit.